# Compress-Archive without recursion on list of files

Tags: powershell

I need to create an archive file of the files in `C:\src\csv` without recursion. It appears that `Compress-Archive` will always recurse subdirectories.

The following code fails. It appears to only be using the file `Name` and not `FullName` in the list of files. In what ways could I overcome this?

```
Compress-Archive -Path (Get-ChildItem -File -Path 'C:\src\csv') -DestinationPath $Env:TEMP\t.zip
```

Comment: Simply add `.FullName` on the end of your parenthesis in the `Path` parameter.

Comment: Or just `GCI C:\src\csv -File | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath $env:TEMP\t.zip`. The `-Path` parameter for `Compress-Archive` accepts piped input.

Answer (score 0):

Specify files `FullName` and indicate an `array` of values with `@()` construct.

```
Compress-Archive -Path @((Get-ChildItem -File -Path 'C:\src\csv').FullName) -DestinationPath $Env:TEMP\t.zip
```

Comment: The extra syntax is unnecessary.  PowerShell's parser is smart enough to figure out little details like that